# What is the scope of the idempotence requirement on PUT operations within REST?

Tags: rest, side-effects, idempotent

Let's imagine I have an object that serializes into JSON like so:

```
{ "Name" : "Mike",
  "Status" : "Too cool for school",
  "Looks" : "Devilishly good"}
```

Now, imagine I have a http://absoluteTruth.foo/{id} (PUT) URI that edits this object. If I call it with a message body that contains:

```
{"Name" : "Michael"}
```

what are the demands of idempotence in the face of requests that (improbably) try to alter the other two values? On one hand, I can see that the PUT request above should result in an object that serializes thusly:

```
{ "Name" : "Michael",
  "Status" : null,
  "Looks" : null}
```

That way, no matter what anybody else does, my PUT operation always *results in* the same output. This, unfortunately, places the requirement on the end user that they do a GET, alter the received data, and send back. (Rich Hickey might admonish you for *complecting* the updates of your various fields.) On the other hand, I can see that it could result in:

```
{ "Name" : "Michael",
  "Status" : "Too cool for school",
  "Looks" : "Devilishly good"}
```

Since we can say that changes to the values of "Status" and "Looks" are not among the *side effects* of PUT when it is called with only the "Name" parameter specified. However, what is returned from subsequent calls to http://absolutetruth.foo/{id} (PUT) might change from time to time if, for example, someone else stops by to rate Michael nee' Mike's looks even more highly.

While this is not, I suspect, an earth-shattering question, the various RFCs I've read, including 2616, are unclear on the point. I lean toward thinking that PUTting with {"Name" : "Michael"} is idempotent enough if it leaves all other values alone, rather than flattening them. Anyone have a definitive answer with an authoritative source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 specifies that:

```
The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied 
Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the 
enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing 
on the origin server.
```

This means that the body you send should be considered as a whole representation of the resource. `PUT` idempotence is a consequence of that.

If you `PUT` `{"Name" : "Michael"}` on `/bar` then your resource will not mention the other "fields" anymore.

If you want to change specifically one attribute, you'll have to define other resources, such as `/bar/name`.

Comment: Hmmm. I accepted it, but begrudgingly. :) It seems like "a modified version" is just vague enough to go either way. If we say that the object _is_ the JSON, then flattening makes sense. If the object merely _represents_ the state of the resource, then it's not at all clear to me that flattening makes sense. It seems to me that the web was based on a document model, where the payload is the thing, and that the RFCs just couldn't have anticipated an object or data model, where the payload merely represents the thing.

Comment: The history of HTTP 1.1 refutes this idea of a document-centric model. It was indeed the result of [very abstract and philosophical discussions](http://www.academia.edu/1788930/CoReWeb_From_Linked_Documentary_Resources_to_Linked_Computational_Resources) (see section 2).

Comment: "was" is the past tense of "be", not the present tense.

Comment: This paper is recent but its references are indeed from the past. Roy Fielding's thesis and HTTP 1.1 specifications are the results of these very abstract discussions to build a non-documentary Web. It depends a lot on what is meant by "resource" and it caused at that time what was called the "[Web identity crisis](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/09/11/deviant.html)".